# Android password after Rebooting the device

Tags: lock-screens, reboot, password

I have not set up any lock screen password, but any time I reboot it asks for the password, saying, 'To start Android, Enter your password.'

A week ago I experimented with the 'Lost your Phone' feature in Android Device Manager on my phone. I've set a password for that, and from then onward, whenever I rebooted, it asks for a password even I've set up. When I rebooted the last time I entered the password I've set up for ADM and luckily it worked. But this time it did not.

I've tried my Google password as well. How do I unlock my phone?

Answer (score 0):

You unlock the phone with the password you defined in ADM, if that doesn't work, you may have to log back in ADM and change the passcode again and wait 15-20 minutes (this is different than the 1-3 days if you change your Google account password), once you have access to the device, you must turn off the password on the device in the Settings - Security - Screen Lock area (may vary slightly by device or Android version) before it will stop prompting you for the password, you cannot clear the password from ADM.